# jQuery customClass syntax (jQuery Selecter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selecter-plugin

I'm attempting to use a jQuery plugin called "[selecter](https://github.com/FormstoneClassic/Selecter)" from Formstone that styles select lists. The CSS has the max-width  set at 30%, which is exactly what is happening on my page, and which is much larger than I want. (I also don't like it being dynamic.) I'd like to control the width on a case by case basis.  The documentation has the following option:

Define a custom CSS class to have multiple visually distinct Selecters on the same page:

```
$("select").selecter({
    customClass: "custom"
});
```

What seems logical to me is that if I have multiple widths I want to have available, I should be able to do something like the following:

```
 $("select").selecter({
        customClass: "width1, width2, width3"
 });
```

...and then define those classes in the CSS like:

```
.width1 {
    width: 200px;    
}

.width2 {
    width: 300px
}
```

etc.

...and have the select tag set up like this:

```
<select class="width1">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately that seems to have no impact on the page.

I also tried:

```
$("select").selecter({
    customClass: document.getElementById("select1").style.width="200px";
});
```

and then within quotes:

```
$("select").selecter({
    customClass: "document.getElementById("select1").style.width="200px";"
});
```

...and that completely removed all of the styling from the select box and it appears as if the plugin isn't installed at all.

How should I be setting the customClass in the jQuery plugin to get the desired result?  I suppose I could put each select list in its own DIV and change the max-width in the plugin's CSS file to 100% , but that seems kind of ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the custom class as an argument to `.selecter()`, it will be applied to all Selecter instances that are instantiated by your call to the plugin. Also, as you've seen, you can't put the class on the `<select>` directly, since Selecter is hiding it and showing its own custom creation

So, if you plan on having multiple types of select boxes, you can include the custom class as a `data-` option on that particular `<select>`. Selecter will read and respect this option.

```
<select name="selecter_custom" data-selecter-options='{"customClass":"width1"}'>

...

$('select').selecter();
```

Now you can apply a width to `.width1` as you'd expect.